# Structural auto-completion of types

Tags: monaco-editor

We are working on integrating Monaco with our web based RAD product built using React. It has a UI to create State (a simple JSON structure) and Event handler editor where the user can write functions to handle component events like onClick etc. We are using Monaco for the Event handler part. A typical event handler looks like this (simplified) -

```
function onClick($state){
     // do something with $state
}
```

Note that `$state` structure is based on the shape of the State which the user created.

Now that the code is hosted in Monaco, we want to let the user see auto-completion of the $state variable. Going over [the closest example](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-javascript-defaults) to this use case in the Monaco Playground, do we need to create a dynamic d.ts around the $state structure for this to work? Or is there a simpler alternative where we sort of inject the State structure into the editor DOM and let it auto complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib**

```
    $.get('../State.d.ts').done(function (data) {
        console.info('done');


        require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' } });

        require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
            monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(data, 'StateObject');
            editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
                value: ['aso.EnvironmentName = "DEV"'
                ].join('\n'),
                language: 'typescript'
            });
        });
    })
```

State.d.ts (you could also supply JSON):

```
interface StateObject {
    CapitalCity: string,
    Population: number,
    ZipCodes: string[]
}
```

and you will git intellisense for that object.

Think of addExtraLib as a using/include/require statement.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what we have resorted to as of now.